# Pick particular primary keys from a database table

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am working with a SQL Server database. I have a table `products` with around 50,000 rows.

The columns in the `products` table are `id` (primary, auto increment), `title`, `price` etc.

I have a second table `Top_ten_products` with columns `id` (primary, auto increment), `product_id`. This table keeps the record of the top ten products.

I want to retrieve the top ten products from the `products` table. But since the `products` table is very large in size, I am searching for a way where I can pop out particular ids from the `products` table without traversing the the whole 50,000 rows.

How can I do that? Thanks in advance

Comment: 50'000 rows - that's **NOTHING** - that's not even "mid-size" for SQL Server! If you have the proper index, getting the top 10 out of 50'000 should be way below a second.

Answer (score 1):

I reread your question and if you mean your Top_Ten_Products table stores the top 10 -- like best 10 -- then it makes a little more sense.

One option would be to use an `INNER JOIN`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Products P
   JOIN Top_Ten_Products T ON P.Product_Id = T.Product_Id
```

And make sure you have indexes on your Product_Id fields.

Another option would be add a field to your Products table for IsTopTen that's a bit.

However, if you're storing the top 10 products by most recent, then I wouldn't recommend having the top_ten table -- no need in that case.

Answer (score 0):

Traversing 50,000 records is what SQL does.

```
select * 
from products 
where id in (select product_id from Top_ten_products)
```

And id primary on Top_ten_products serves no purpose.
Just make product_id the PK.